# Prove there exists $c\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|c| \leq 1$ and $f(z)=ce^{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $(a_k)_{k\geq 0}$ be a real sequence such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} a_k =+\infty$. Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function such that:
$$\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N},~~|f^{(n)}(a_k)|\leq e^{-a_k} $$

Prove there exists $c\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|c| \leq 1$ and,
$$\forall z \in\mathbb{C}, ~~f(z)=ce^{-z}$$

Do you have an idea about how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $k \ge 0$ consider the power series expansion of $f$ in $a_k$:
$$
f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j^{(k)}(z-a_k)^j.
$$
Now $|f^{(n)}(a_k)| = |n!c_n^{(k)}| \le \exp(-a_k)$ $(n \ge 0)$. Thus
$$
|f(z)| \le \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\exp(-a_k)}{j!}|z-a_k|^j = \exp(-a_k+|z-a_k|). 
$$
Thus
$$
|\exp(z)f(z)| \le \exp(\Re(z-a_k)+|z-a_k|) \quad (k \ge 0). 
$$
Now $a_k \to \infty$ implies $\Re(z-a_k)+|z-a_k| \to 0$ $(k \to \infty)$ for each $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Thus $|\exp(z)f(z)|\le 1$ on $\mathbb{C}$.
By Liouville's Theorem $f(z)=c \exp(-z)$ for some $c$ with $|c| \le 1$.